# How can we extend negative numbers to left side in a deque in python?

Tags: python, deque

If I type the following code in python 3 to extend the negative numbers to the left of the deque

```
de=collections.deque([])
de.extendleft('-1-2-3-4-5-6')
```

I'm getting an output like this

```
deque(['6', '-', '5', '-', '4', '-', '3', '-', '2', '-', '1', '-'])
```

instead I want a output like:

```
deque(['-6','-5''-4','-3','-2','-1'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving string as input. Because of that it's considering `-` this also a element.

```
from collections import deque

x = '-1-2-3-4-5-6'.replace('-', ' -').strip()
de = deque([])
de.extendleft(x.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a list not a string. Use `'-1-2-3-4-5-6'.replace('-', ' -').split(' ')[1:]`

```
import collections
de=collections.deque([])
de.extendleft([-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6])
```

---

```
import collections
de=collections.deque([])
de.extendleft('-1-2-3-4-5-6'.replace('-', ' -').split(' ')[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but works:
Instead of

```
de.extendleft('-1-2-3-4-5-6')
```

Use

```
de.extendleft('-1-2-3-4-5-6'.replace('-',',-').split(',')[1:])
```

What does it do:

- The `replace('-',',-')` adds a comma that will work to separate with `split`. So in this first step you get:

  ```
  '-1-2-3-4-5-6'.replace('-',',-')=',-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6'
  ```
- In `split(',')` you quit the comma added before and you can split this into a list:

  ```
  ',-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6'.split(',')=['', '-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6']
  ```
- Finally, you must quit that useless space in the position `0`, so that's why you put in the end the `[1:]`, so the final part becomes

  ```
  ['', '-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6'][1:]=['-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6']
  ```

So in the end the list becomes

```
['-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6']
```

**EDIT**: Don't follow this answer, it's better if you use a space instead of a comma as a separator.